# How to create constraint for limiting max childs

Tags: symfony, symfony-validator

Let's say I have two entities `Bus` and `People` with a relation `OneToMany` between them.
Bus can hold a maximum of 10 persons.

How to create a constraint to control this?

For example:

```
* @MyAssert\ParentMaxChild(max=10)

* @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Webface\CharacterBundle\Entity\Bus", inversedBy="wac")
* @ORM\JoinColumn(name="bus_id", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=false)

private $bus;
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [Count constraint](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Count.html).

In your `Bus` class, add the constraint in the Person annotation:

```
/**
 * ... Rest of the annotation ...
 * @Assert\Count(
 *      max = "10",
 *      maxMessage = "Bus can hold a maximum of 10 persons."
 * )
 */
protected $persons;
```

Note that you can specify a `min` parameter and the according message.